# Putting a comma and space in a mixed HTML/PHP variable

Tags: php, html, variables, syntax-error

How would I correctly put a comma and space in between the two variables that define `$keywords`?

What I currently have causes a syntax error:

```
$keywords = "'.$title.',$nbsp'.$_POST['developer'].'";
```

Comment: Don't forget the HTML escaping on input variables.

Answer (score 2):

When you're interpolating an array element into a string, you have two choices.

One, leave out the quotes around the key:

```
$keywords = "'.$title.',$nbsp'.$_POST[developer].'";
```

Two, put curly braces around it:

```
$keywords = "'.$title.',$nbsp'.{$_POST['developer']}.'";
```

Or, you could use concatenation instead of interpolation:

```
$keywords = "'.$title.',$nbsp'." . $_POST['developer'] . ".'";
```

Answer (score 1):

$keywords = $title.', '.$_POST['developer'];

Answer (score 0):

It's alittle messy what you have there but I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
$keywords = "$title, $_POST['developer']";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sprintf for cleaner code?

```
$keywords = sprintf('%s,$nbsp;%s' $title, $_POST['developer']);
```

Answer (score 0):

$keywords = "'.$title.',$nbsp'.$_POST['developer'].'";

Another nicer take on this:

```
$post_developer = $_POST['developer'];

$keywords = <<<HEREDOC

   $title, $nsbp$post_developer

HEREDOC;
// the above line has to be single, no spaces before or after it.
```